# Is there a way to get the list of elements which are currently visible in viewport having certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm Having more than 2000 html elements present in my document having class "abc".
When I scroll(Up/Down) **I want list of html Elements present in my viewport having class 'abc'** as I want to perform some activity on those elements which are present in viewport not on all the elements with class 'abc'

Comment: maybe get a list of all $(".abc") elements and just check their boundries to see if they are within the viewport?

Comment: Thanks @Banana for ur reply..Ya I have tried that already, but having a list of 2000 elements and then checking every element for its presence in viewport is very heavy task performance wise.Is there any function in jQuery/javascript which can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the Viewport plugin from here: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

here is a link to download it from their github: <kbd>[Viewport.js](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_viewport/blob/master/jquery.viewport.js)</kbd>

using this plugin is very simple, to find all the `.abc` elements inside the viewport you simple add `:in-viewport` to your selector:

```
$('.abc:in-viewport');
```

here is a live demo: <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/p55Ct/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I created a Viewport class just for this purpose: https://github.com/gburghardt/viewport

It also has pseudo events for when the user stops scrolling and when the orientation if the viewport changes. Handy for mobile devices.